# C++ speed up method call

Tags: c++, performance, methods, call

I am working on a very time consuming application and I want to speed it up a little. I analyzed the runtime of single parts using the clock() function of the ctime library and found something, which is not totally clear to me.

I have time prints outside and inside of a method, lets call it Method1. The print inside Method1 includes the whole body of it, only the return of a float is exluded of course. Well, the thing is, that the print outside states twice to three times the time of the print inside Method1. It's obvious, that the print outside should state more time, but the difference seems quite big to me.

My method looks as follows, I am using references and pointers as parameters to prevent copying of data. Note, that the data vector includes 330.000 pointers to instances.

```
float ClassA::Method1(vector<DataClass*>& data, TreeClass* node)
{
    //start time measurement
    vector<Mat> offset_vec_1 = vector<Mat>();
    vector<Mat> offset_vec_2 = vector<Mat>();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
    {
        DataClass* cur_data = data.at(i);
        Mat offset1 = Mat();
        Mat offset2 = Mat();

        getChildParentOffsets(cur_data, node, offset1, offset2);

        offset_vec_1.push_back(offset1);
        offset_vec_2.push_back(offset2);
    }

    float ret = CalculateCovarReturnTrace(offset_vec_1) + CalculateCovarReturnTrace(offset_vec_2);
    //end time measurement
    return ret;
}
```

Is there any "obvious" way to increase the call speed? I would prefer to keep the method for readability reasons, thus, can I change anything to gain a speed up?

I am appreciating any suggestions!

Comment: Unless you find a way to inline your function, there's not much potential to _increase call speed_.

Comment: One obvious way would be setting compiler's optimization flags. But you should describe in detail what the method does, the method signature does not give us any hits whatsoever.

Comment: There may be destructor calls taking up time... If there's lots of complicated structures created within the function, there may be lots to cleanup

Comment: As it stands, two parameters (one by reference, the other a pointer) and returning a float won't incur much overhead themselves

Comment: Too few details given. Is `Method` a virtual function? What the target architecture? What are compiler optimization flags?

Comment: @SelçukCihan You are right, I added the code above.

Comment: It seems like there's a lot of calculations still happening in the return statement (two calls to methods which take in a 330000 long vector). So if you're not including that in your time measurements, it's to be expected that you'll see a huge difference.

Comment: Also, if you're worried about performance, you should probably remove the `= Mat()`, add a call to `std::move` to your calls to `push_back`, and make sure that `CalculateCovarReturnTrace` takes a vector reference, instead of a vector value.

Comment: @SergeyA No, its not virtual, nothing extraordinary. I am working in Visual Studio on Windows 8, CPU is i7, x64. I have not set any optimization flag (I have to look into these). Can I assume a big impact by using the right optimization flag?

Comment: @Icarus make sure you're running the project in Release mode (_not_ Debug mode). It can make a huge difference.

Comment: @JSQuareD These calculations are of course INCLUDED of the time measurement. I simplified the code above and thus removed the time measurement related code. Sorry for not pointing that out.

Comment: @Icarus they should be _included_.

Comment: There's still 660,000 `Mat` deallocations occurring after the return statement.

Comment: @JSQuareD Ok, that was embarassing.. I meant included, these are included in the measurements (as added by comments above in the code).

Comment: @vu1p3n0x I think you have a good point with the deallocations. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Print the assembly language for the function.  Ask yourself if there can be any modifications made that can simplify the assembly language.  Also raise the optimization levels.

Comment: Try moving the `offset` variables outside (before) the `for` loop.  No reason to create a new `Mat` variable each time (unless there are reset or initialization issues with the variables).

Comment: Declare the `offset` vectors as static, and specify a starting capacity.  Vector resizing eats a lot of processor time.

Comment: Have you tried *unrolling* the loop?  You may want to raise the optimization level and see if the compiler is already performing this (by checking the assembly language generated by the compiler).

Comment: Have you tried optimizing `getParentChildOffsets` or at least measured the execution time?  It is a good candidate to have optimized or maybe inlined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your updated code, the only code between the end time measurement and the measurement after the function call is the destructors for constructed objects in the function. That being the two vectors of 330,000 `Mat`s each. Which will likely take some time depending on the resources used by each of those `Mat`s.

Comment: A general problem that can occur with stuff like this is that you might very quickly have thousands of copies of these dynamic objects lying-around in the heap, awaiting garbage-collection ... and, not only is garbage collection now fairly expensive, when it does come, but the overall heap-area is big.  (Ergo, serious likelihood of incurring lots of page-faults.)  If an "erase" operation on, say, this Mat object, puts the removed elements into some sort of free-list for recycling, that might help.  But if it simply "free()s" everything, it wouldn't.  VM paging  is what kills clock-time.

Comment: The Mat's are rather small, they only contain 3 floats. As such, they should need less than 8 MB.

Comment: Hmmm, just curious are these OpenCV `Mat`s or some other structure? What I'm really asking is akin to what @MikeRobinson was saying. Because if they are individual allocations, that would take some time to free, but if they're not and therefore be part of one continuous allocation via `std::vector` then I'd expect it to be fast

Comment: @vu1p3n0x These are OpenCV `Mat`s, yes. And yes, I know what you mean. However, how could I know, if they are really continuously stored in memory? Thing is, I do allocate them on the Stack and then I add them to the `vector` -> are the `Mat`s then copied to it, meaning that the initial allocation on the Stack needs to be "deleted"?

Comment: `std::vector` is guaranteed to store its elements contiguously, but the resources used by the structures within that vector would be allocated separately.

Comment: because `cv::Mat`s are resizeable, they must store their data elsewhere

Comment: Yeah, thats true. Well, I'm afraid there is not much I can do. Thank you.

Comment: If it is that big of an issue, there are things you CAN do but are a bit more involved, and a different topic entirely. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Without trying to lay claim to any of the comments made by others to the OP ...

(1) The short-answer might well be, *"no."*  This function appears to be quite clear, and it's doing a lot of work 30,000 times.  Then, it's doing a calculation over "all that data."

(2) Consider *re-using* the "offset1" and "offset2" matrices, instead of creating entirely new ones for each iteration.  It remains to be seen, of course, whether this would actually be faster.  (And in any case, *see below,* it amounts to "diddling the code.")

(3) Therefore, borrowing from *The Elements of Programming Style:* "Don't 'diddle' code to make it faster: find a better algorithm."  And in this case, there just might not be one.  You might need to address the runtime issue by "throwing silicon at it," and I'd suggest that the first thing to do would be to add as much RAM as possible to this computer.  A process that "deals with a lot of data" is very-exposed to virtual memory page-faults, each of which requires on the order of *milli-*seconds to resolve.  (Those hundredths of a second add-up real fast.)

I personally do not see anything *categorically* wrong with this code, nor anything that would *categorically* cause it to run faster.  Nor would I advocate re-writing *("diddling")* the code from the very-clear expression of it that you have right now.

Comment: I upvoted. But I do want to note that you didn't actually address the question. You made suggestions about how to optimize the method, but you did not offer an explanation as to why the inner measurement shows a much smaller value than the outer measurement. (Possibly because of Matrix deallocations, as vu1p3n0x noted.)

Comment: Indeed I did not address the question, because any opinion I could offer would only be an educated guess ... a guess very similar to yours.

Comment: Thank you. I will try your suggestion in (2). Regarding (3) You are right. However, I know for sure, that the RAM does not run out (I have already optimized that).